# Library to recognize Dutch dates in text?

Tags: python, date

I have a series of strings (in Dutch) that contain a date in either a DD-MM-YYYY format or in a textual format DD month YYYY. See an example selection here: https://paste.ee/p/XZLha. I'm looking for a Python (2.7) library that is able to recognize the date from these text strings.

- **dateutil** is not able to properly parse Dutch
- **dateparser** is not able to parse fuzzy strings - it only accepts strings with dates and days. It can handle Dutch dates though.

I'd like to get your input on possible solutions. I'm considering stripping the text around the dates away and working with dateparser.

Comment: You could always use regex/string matching and do it yourself.

Comment: That's what I'm considering to use (regex+list of Dutch month names) if I can't find a suitable library to do it for me. There are quite some different cases that I'd need to account for :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example using regular expressions as @Shiva recommended.  It will probably need some refinement but the concept is there:

```
import re

SOURCE_DATA_SAMPLE = """gedaan te Amsterdam, op 13-4-2010, door
gedaan te Amsterdam, op 13 april 2010, door
gedaan te Amsterdam, op 12 juni 2003, door
gedaan te Amsterdam, op 12 juni 2002, door
Aldus gedaan op 24 oktober 2003 door
Aldus gedaan op 5 december 2003 door
Aldus gedaan op 5 december 2003 door
Aldus gedaan op 8 april 2004 door
Aldus gedaan op 16 april 2004 door
Aldus gedaan op 23 april 2004 door
Aldus gedaan op 10 september 2004 door
Aldus gedaan op 30 september 2004 door"""

DATE_REGEX = re.compile("(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})|(\d{1,2} \w.*? \d{4})")

def find_date(line):
    matched = DATE_REGEX.search(line)
    if (matched):
        return matched.group(0)
    else:
        return None

for line in SOURCE_DATA_SAMPLE.split("\n"):
    date = find_date(line)
    print(date)
```

There's a great site called Regex101 that can help writing expressions; the sample I used for the above is here: https://regex101.com/r/wMFfx4/2

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

can do this from the standard library.

If the following gives you a `ValueError: time data 'Oktober' does not match format '%B'`:

```py
print(datetime.datetime.strptime("Oktober", "%B"))
```

You can set your locale to whatever it is that you need. Dutch being

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "nl_NL")
```

Then through this you can easily parse what you need:

```py
print(datetime.datetime.strptime("Oktober", "%B"))
>>> datetime.datetime(1900, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Beautiful!
I feel like a wizard doing
`print(datetime.datetime.strptime("mei", "%b").month)`.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `datetime` module's [`datetime.strpdate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) can parse dates [in a number of formats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), including locale-specific ones. You still need to extract a date from the text first - either with a regex of some other means of analysis (e.g. maybe they are in some known, very specific parts of the text).